# Which way would the soldier roll?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

In the army you have APC's: a truck with an opening at the back. Suppose a soldier fell out of the opening. Would they be carried forward towards the front of the vehicle, or backwards away from the vehicle, or neither and stay where they were?

I'm just applying the laws of physics; the soldier has no agency here. I could draw a diagram if that helps. I am going to guess that the forward momentum of having been ina vehicle will remain after he falls out, so the soldier will fall and be carried forward towards the vehicle. But if I am wrong I won't be surprised.

Comment: They would roll to the closest side so as to not get run over by the APC following ...

Comment: Well that is true! But I wasn't asking a Bear Grylls type question! I was in an APC once and this was debated by some people in it!

Comment: Are they jumping out the back, or just falling? If the latter, they'll roll in the direction of the vehicle's motion, but slower than the vehicle because of friction. So from the perspective of someone on the ground they are rolling in the direction of the vehicle, but from the perspective of someone on the vehicle they will be moving away from the vehicle.

Comment: As in the OP [lack of agency] the soldier is falling out without making an attempt to jump or change direction etc.If this goes in a relativity direction I don't mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to be in the Army, so I can easily visualise the situation you describe. When the soldier rolls off, or more likely jumps off, he will continue to travel in the same direction as the lorry or the personnel carrier, but at a rapidly reducing speed when his feet or body touch the ground. I assume the vehicle is travelling at least at running speed. No, you haven't got it wrong, except that the soldier will not be carried toward the vehicle but in the same direction as the vehicle, which is probably what you meant to say. If the vehicle were travelling at snail's pace, hardly moving at all, the soldier might move in the opposite direction to the vehicle. It would be best if he avoided landing in a standing position facing the direction from which he had come, which sometimes happens in parachute landings.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

All good answers. I just want to say that one other good approach to problems of this kind is to use relativity. I don’t mean Einstein, but the simple Newtonian kind: “In ten minutes, Cambridge will arrive at this train”.

Looking at things from the point of view of the vehicle, you have a stationary vehicle and the ground moving backwards underneath the vehicle. The soldier falling off a stationary vehicle will be much easier to visualise.

The key to problems like this is to make them obvious first and only put the equations in afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a roller instead of the soldier. In the ground frame, before touching the ground, the roller will have forward momentum but no angular velocity. After touching the ground, friction will try to oppose relative velocity and make the roller role in the forward direction.

Comment: I was thinking that a tennis ball would also be a good example.

Answer (score 1):

To make the analysis much easier consider a sphere rather than a soldier.

The FBD for a sphere on the ground might look like this with $v$ the linear velocity of the centre of mass of the sphere and $\omega$ the angular velocity of the sphere.

Initially $v$ would be the velocity of the truck and the angular velocity would be zero.

Once the sphere hit the ground there would be a frictional force $f$ 
acting on the sphere due to the ground as there is relative movement between the sphere and the ground at their point of contact.

You can think of that frictional force doing two things to get to the no slipping between the sphere and the ground $v= r\omega$ where $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

The frictional force **decreases** the linear velocity whilst at the same time applying a torque about the centre of mass $C$ which **increases** the angular velocity.

This continues until the no slipping condition is satisfied.

So the forward speed of the soldier would decrease whilst the angular speed of the soldier (rolling) would increase.

[image]

Comment: You have me interested now. I guess that we could extend the question and say more than one sphere falls out of the back of the APC. [armored personell carrier] Then you would have three things: the truck and the two spheres that flal out at different times. So you could try to consider the bigger situation of N number of spheres. Now it's getting complicated. Simple things lead to complicated things lol.